# lerp with time parameter?

Tags: interpolation

I'm implementing lerp function with time parameter and got stucked at how to involve time(t) in the formular.
I have the original coordinates of vP(xP,yP) and the destination coordinates of vM(xM,yM). And it was asked to go through the distance at exactly three seconds.

I know from the lerp equation I can get any points between vP and vM.
But how can I achieve the goal of three seconds? 
Thanks!

Comment: Hint: find the velocity vector $\vec v$ between two points and express the position of a point at time $t$ as the sum of $vP(xP,yP)$ and the product of $\vec v t$.

Answer (score 1):

In vector notation, the position $\vec x$ is given by:
$$
\vec x=
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_P\\y_P
\end{bmatrix}
+\frac{t}{3}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_M-x_P\\y_M-y_P
\end{bmatrix}
$$